# differences between 2 JUnit Assert classes

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, assert

The JUnit framework contains 2 `Assert` classes (in different packages, obviously) and the methods on each appear to be very similar. Can anybody explain why this is?

The classes I'm referring to are: [`junit.framework.Assert`](http://junit.org/junit/javadoc/4.5/junit/framework/Assert.html) and [`org.junit.Assert`](http://junit.org/junit/javadoc/4.5/org/junit/Assert.html).

Comment: In Intellij IDEA, you can exclude `junit.framework.*` from the static import dropdown in `Editor->General->Auto Import->Exclude from Import and Completion`.

Answer (score 250, accepted):

The old method (of JUnit 3) was to mark the test-classes by extending `junit.framework.TestCase`. That inherited `junit.framework.Assert` itself and your test class gained the ability to call the assert methods this way.

Since version 4 of JUnit, the framework uses `Annotations` for marking tests. So you no longer need to extend `TestCase`. But that means, the assert methods aren't available. But you can make a static import of the new `Assert` class. That's why all the assert methods in the new class are static methods. So you can import it this way:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

After this static import, you can use this methods without prefix.

At the redesign they also moved to the new package `org.junit` that follows better the normal conventions for package naming.

Comment: This answer is not entirely correct, you can make static imports of methods in  the class junit.framework.Assert  and org.junit.Assert. It is, however, probably a good idea to stick to the org.junit.Assert class  since it is newer , slightly rewritten and probably meant as a replacement.

Answer (score 82):

JUnit 3.X: `junit.framework.Assert`

JUnit 4.X: `org.junit.Assert`

Prefer the newest one, especially when running JDK5 and higher with annotation support.

Answer (score 21):

There is in fact a functional change: `org.junit.Assert` will complain if you use the two-argument `assertEquals()` with `float` or `double`, while `junit.framework.Assert` will silently autobox it.

Answer (score 5):

I believe they are refactoring from `junit.framework` to `org.junit` and `junit.framework.Assert` is maintained for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

In Android Studio (and so in IntelliJ too), you can globally exclude `junit.framework` from auto-import proposal.

You can set the scope between `IDE` or `Project`. If you don't have projects which use JUnit 3 you can safely stay with IDE scope.

Setting position:

> Preferences -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I did a rough source code compare and there are no serious changes. A lot of comments were added in `org.junit.Assert` and some refactorings are done. The only change is the comparison with `Arrays`. There are some code cleanups, but there's (imho) **no functional change**.

Comment: I believe @David Moles is correct, and this would be a functional change.