# JUnit java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: junit.framework.ComparisonFailure.getExpected()Ljava/lang/String

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I am getting the following exception from a test case that ran successfully before but now it throws this exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: junit.framework.ComparisonFailure.getExpected()Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestListener.testFailure(JUnit4TestListener.java:63)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$4.notifyListener(RunNotifier.java:100)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier$SafeNotifier.run(RunNotifier.java:41)
    at org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier.fireTestFailure(RunNotifier.java:97)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner$OldTestClassAdaptingListener.addError(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner$OldTestClassAdaptingListener.addFailure(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:64)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.addFailure(TestResult.java:46)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:127)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:208)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:203)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Anyone know what is causing this? It seems like an internal issue with the JUnit runner.

Comment: can you post the code at the line where it is failing?

Comment: what version of junit are you using? It looks like others have seen this with 4.5.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot post the entire test method cause it contains some business logic. However there is nothing unusual about the assertions just simple assertEquals(). The stack trace doesn't give me a specific line from the test class that its failing on. The test ran fine before so I'm not sure why its throwing this exception. I have never seen this exception before.

Comment: I am using JUnit Version 4.8.1

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `getExpected()` method on `junit.framework.ComparisonFailure` was only added in JUnit 3.8.2 (remember, `junit.framework` package is from JUnit 3.8, whereas JUnit 4 uses `org.junit`). The method wasn't there in 3.8.1, which is the most common version of 3.x still out there.

I think the method was added for easier migration to JUnit 4 tooling, and occasionally this exception pops up on older code bases that use JUnit 3.8.  The Eclipse JUnit 4 test runner would appear to switch back to calling the `junit.framework.*` code when running JUnit 3.8 tests.

SO I'm guessing you still have JUnit 3.8.1 lurking about on your classpath, and it's clashing with the Eclipse test runner. Either get rid of that JAR, or "upgrade" it to 3.8.2.

Comment: If you do not see it in your project dependencies then one of the libraries might be using 3.8. If you cannot remove the library from there then try using the @RunWith(JUnit4.class) annotation.

Answer (score 12):

This can also occur if you're using JUnit 4 but import the `Assert` class from the old `junit.framework` package (rather than the new `org.junit` package)

Check both your imports and your static imports - the culprit for me was `import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;`

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291003/differences-between-2-junit-assert-classes

Answer (score 6):

The same error occurred to me when running my test class in eclipse but my solution was slightly different.

My setup was that I had junit-4.10 jar in the classpath but my test class was using junit 3 and the exception only occurred if the assertEquals method failed.

The problem was that eclipse was still using the junit 4 runner so I changed it by editing the configuration (selecting the "Run Configuration" in eclipse, then selecting the test class and then changing the "Test Runner" in the dropdown from "JUnit 4" to "JUnit 3").

Answer (score 2):

The problem in my case was junit-4.5.jar added directly as a library to the project.

My solution was to remove dependency on the junit jar from Eclipse project and rely on the JUnit plugin library. That one is added automatically or can be added manually by clicking Add Library button on the project's library screen.

That one takes JUnit from plugin and has a reference similar to this:

```
.../Eclipse/plugins/org.junit_4.12.0.v201504281640
```

It's also necessary to move the JUnit library on top of the list in Order and Export tab. Checking the checkbox for export is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the problem, but it was because I was using JUnit 4.1.  I switched to 4.4 and the problem went away.

Answer (score -1):

I only had the issue after I upgraded to the Kepler version of Eclipse.  The test would run fine if I ran "All" tests.  But when I ran a single method test it would fail with this error.

I found this answer and thought I'd share it here to help someone else in the future.  The long and short of it is upgrade to Junit 4.4 or better

https://www.gotraveltech.com/confluence/display/COOK/My+Eclipse  Scroll down to "How do I run individual JUnit 4.x.x tests in MyEclipse?"

Answer (score -1):

Checking for **dependencies and imported libraries** versions is most productive in this case.

For example, `@Test` annotation could be imported from `org.junit.Test` and not `@org.testng.annotations.Test`. For Android project it could result in an error like:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ...