# Difference between org.junit.Test and junit.framework.Test packages

Tags: selenium, webdriver, junit4, junit3

```
<project name="JunitSuite" basedir="." default="clean">

    <property name="${src}" value="./src/JunitSuiteProject" />
    <property name="${build}" value="./build" />
    <property name="package" value="JunitSuiteProject"/>
    <property name= "jar" value="./build/jar"/>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="./build"/>
        <mkdir dir="./build"/>
        <mkdir dir="./build/jar"/>
    </target>

<target name="run">
        <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes" showoutput="yes">
            <classpath location="C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar"/>
            <classpath location="E:\Swaroop Don't Touch\Selenium\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.junit_3.8.2.v3_8_2_v20100427-1100\junit.jar"/>
            <classpath location="C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\*.jar"/>
            <classpath location="E:\Swaroop Don't Touch\Selenium\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32\eclipse\plugins\"/>
            <formatter type="brief" usefile="false"/>               
        <batchtest fork="yes"> 
            <fileset dir="C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib" includes="selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="E:\Swaroop Don't Touch\Selenium\eclipse-jee-juno-SR2-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.junit_3.8.2.v3_8_2_v20100427-1100" includes="junit.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib" includes="*.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="./build" includes="**/AllTests.*"/> 
        </batchtest>
     </junit>
</target>   

    <target name="compile">
        <javac srcdir="./src/JunitSuiteProject" destdir="./build" includeantruntime="true">
                  <classpath location="C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.9.2\lib\selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar" />
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="jar">
        <jar destfile="./build/jar/JunitSuite.jar" basedir="./build">
        </jar>
      </target>

</project>
    **************************************************************

    package JunitSuiteProject;


    import junit.framework.TestSuite;
    import junit.framework.Test;
    import org.junit.runners.Suite;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

    @RunWith(Suite.class)
    @SuiteClasses({JunitTest1.class})


    public class AllTests extends TestSuite{

        public static Test Suite(){
        TestSuite g = new TestSuite();
        g.addTest(new JunitTest1("testprintTest"));
        return g;
    }
        public static void main(String[]args){
            junit.textui.TestRunner.run(Suite());
        }
    }
```

Could anyone let me know what is the issue here when i have specified the location of Jars inside Junit why am i getting ClassNotFoundException Error when i trigger the Ant file.

```
The output says: 

[junit] Running AllTests
    [junit] Testsuite: AllTests
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Time elapsed: 0 sec
    [junit] Null Test:  Caused an ERROR
    [junit] AllTests
    [junit] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AllTests
```

The junit used is 3.8 version and it is executing fine as a junit test but giving error when started from build.xml file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [differences between 2 JUnit Assert classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291003/differences-between-2-junit-assert-classes)

Answer (score 39):

The `junit.framework.Test` package is the legacy namespace used by older projects that used JUnit v3 which was for versions of Java that did not support annotations.

The `org.junit.Test` package is the new namespace used by JUnit v4 which requires Java v1.5 or later for its annotations.   Use JUnit 4 and the latest Java if possible because the new annotations are vastly superior.

The current distributions of JUnit 4 include a copy of the old namespace to allow easy migration; however you should avoid using JUnit3 form for new tests and convert old tests to JUnit 4 as you can.

In JUnit 4 both packages are included in the library jar for migrations purposes but you should use org.junit.Test for new code and those test do not need to extend TestCase.

You can see [a basic example of Junit4 test case](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: I am unable to understand how ant is talking to junit even after providing the classpath as in above code. enlighten me if i am wrong as i am new to junit and ant......

Comment: Your Ant build.xml is referencing 3.8 (org.junit_3.8.2.v3_8_2_v20100427-1100).  What do you mean by "executing fine as a junit test "?  Do you mean inside Eclipse run as JUnit test?  If so that works because Eclipse must be using a V4.x of Junit. You are using annotation so you must use the v4.x library in place of the above.