# What is the difference between the org.junit package and the junit.framework package?

Tags: java, junit

Whenever I use a Junit assert in my code, my IDE (Intellij IDEA 12) politely offers to static-import it for me:

```
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertTrue;
```

However, it always gives me the choice of importing either the "org.junit" version or the "junit.framework" version:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
```

I can't find a clear answer online about what the difference is between these two packages - is there a difference?   If so, what is it?   They both come out of exactly the same Junit4 jar, so what's going on?

Comment: You can always download the source jar as well and debug into the method code (assertTrue) to find out which package it is using.

Comment: Or just hover over the method on the editor!

Comment: possible duplicate of [differences between 2 JUnit Assert classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291003/differences-between-2-junit-assert-classes)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`org.junit.*` is `JUnit 4+`. The other is previous versions.

There's backwards compatibility, so `junit.framework.*` is included in `junit-4.x.jar`.

Comment: So which should be used?

Comment: @Edmund If you have access to the newer version, obviously that one.

Comment: Why are they both still in the same jar file 4.9?

Comment: @powder366 As mentioned in the second paragraph, for backwards compatibility. You can now add the new jar and start using new features, while the old ones still work.

Comment: OK. I think they should remove it. Provide a jar for the old library (or the other way around). Now it's to easy to pick the wrong...

Comment: If you use Eclipse, add org.junit.Assert to Window / Preferences / Java / Editor / Content Assist / Favorites and use the unqualified method names in the code, Eclipse will add the correct static import.