# JUnit which assertEquals should I use?

Tags: junit, junit4

I use

```
assertEquals(String, String)
```

in a JUnit test. Netbeans (or is it Maven?) suggest that I add an import of one of:

```
org.junit.assert.assertEquals
junit.framework.assert.assertEquals
junit.framework.testcase.assertEquals
```

Which one should I use and why?

Edit:

As compared to the question [differences between 2 JUnit Assert classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291003/differences-between-2-junit-assert-classes) this question lists three possible imports as compared to two for the other question.

Comment: The junit.framework contains older version classes. The org.junit is the way of annotating methods as tests. 
Here is a link which would explain it better 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291003/differences-between-2-junit-assert-classes[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291003/differences-between-2-junit-assert-classes

Comment: Where does maven suggest this?

Comment: Ok I am not sure its Maven. Maybe Netbeans suggests it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [Do not use any classes in junit.framework or junit.extensions](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Getting-started)

Package `junit.framework.*` was used in JUnit 3.

Package `org.junit.*` is used in JUnit 4.