# Warning: The method assertEquals from the type Assert is deprecated

Tags: java, junit

Since the method `Assert.assertEquals` is deprecated, which method are we supposed to use now?

The following code:

```
String arg1 = "test";
String arg2 = "me";

Assert.assertEquals(arg1, arg2);
```

Gives the following warnings:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> - The method assertEquals(String, String) from the type Assert is deprecated
> - The type Assert is deprecated

Comment: possible duplicate of [differences between 2 JUnit Assert classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291003/differences-between-2-junit-assert-classes)

Answer (score 357, accepted):

You're using `junit.framework.Assert` instead of `org.junit.Assert`.

Comment: Thanks.... i realized that later after i posted this.... I still think it's worth including here as a question/answer, as it may pop up for others, and now they'll find this when they google it.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/291045/411282) to the question linked above provides some additional context.

Comment: To future people who also found this useful, please don't comment a thank you - just upvote the question and answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment it's not a big deal, but we don't want this answer getting cluttered.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is also deprecated in org.junit.Assert too. I think as is commented on by Tommy.qichang below, it requires an additional parameter for delta (level of precision within which is considered correct).

Comment: This question is about comparing Strings and not floats. For Strings it is not deprecated.

Answer (score 57):

this method also encounter a deprecate warning:

```
org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(float expected,float actual) //deprecated
```

It is because currently junit prefer a third parameter rather than just two float variables input.

The third parameter is delta:

```
public static void assertEquals(double expected,double actual,double delta) //replacement
```

this is mostly used to deal with inaccurate Floating point calculations

for more information, please refer this problem: [Meaning of epsilon argument of assertEquals for double values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686755/meaning-of-epsilon-argument-of-assertequals-for-double-values)

Comment: Delta is the value that the 2 numbers can be off by. So it will assert to true as long as Math.abs(expected - actual) < delta. Use 0 if you want 100% accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

When I use Junit4,
import junit.framework.Assert;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
the warning info is :The type of Assert is deprecated

when import like this：
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
the warning has disappeared

possible duplicate of [differences between 2 JUnit Assert classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291003/differences-between-2-junit-assert-classes)